# How to append numeric values to a array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsarray

i have some text which is separated by  space@" ".i displayed this array from DB named delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish (array name) to a textview in the below formate.

```
self.multiPageView.text=[delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

multipageview is the textview,my need is to put numbers between these space.means i have 3 text which is separated by space for e.g.: my name is icoder   my old is twenty   my passion is coding etc etc,i need to set this text to 1 my name is icoder 2 my old is twenty 3 my passion is coding etc etc,how can i appen like this.i already got the text correctly but need in this formate.the DB does not have the numbers,i have to put numbers between separate text.

is anyone have the idea how to implement this..i hope you understand my question.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**: I have rewritten this to use an NSMutableString as this won't hammer the autorelease pool like my original version.

```
NSMutableString *combined = [NSMutableString string];
for(NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < [delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish count]; idx++) {
    [combined appendFormat:@" %d %@", 
                            idx + 1, 
                            [delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish objectAtIndex:idx]];
}

self.multiPageView.text = combined;
```

Comment: i put your code,but getting this warning in second line combined = [combined stringByAppendingFormat:@" %d %@", idx, [// here i get the warning delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish ObjectAtIndex:idx]]; instance method-objectatindex not found( retune type default to id)

Comment: `ObjectAtIndex` should have a lower-case `o`

Comment: I've fixed the ObjectAtIndex typo.

Comment: @Jenox - I was about to rewrite this to use an NSMutableString as this version will hammer the autorelease pool depending on how many items are in the array.

Comment: @mttrb agin the app crashes ,the log says"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 31 beyond bounds [0 .. 30]'
"

Comment: @stackiphone - Sorry, the perils of writing code without being able to run it. Try this completely new version.  If this one doesn't work it might be time for me to take a break :)

Comment: @stackiphone - You probably want to change the fourth line to `idx + 1` if you don't want them numbered from 0.  I've edited my answer to reflect this.